# How to get the previous value from string array c#(Unity)

Tags: unity, c#, android

I have this example data

> Data: P  ,B  ,B  ,T  ,P

This must be something like this

[image]

But what is happening to me is this

[image]

here's my code

```
string[,] table = new string[104, 6];
string newPreviousValue = "placeholder";
int xIndex = -1;
int yIndex = 0;
if (result.Equals(newPreviousValue) &&  yIndex < table.GetLength(1) - 1)
{
    yIndex += 1;
    table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}
            
else
{
     xIndex += 1;
     yIndex = 0;
     table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}
```

So you won't get confuse the `result` variable is the **data** generator.
What could be missing on my condition?

I tried doing something like this

`if (result.Equals(newPreviousValue) && result.Equals(newPreviousValueTie) &&  yIndex < table.GetLength(1) - 1)` but what's happening here is they're all in y axis falling in line .

Comment: What's the rule that determines when something can stack in the same column as a dissimilar entry (Tie stacking on Banker) versus when it can't?

Comment: what could possibly the remedy with this @DMGregory

Comment: I don't know because you haven't answered the question I asked you above.

Comment: As what said @DMGregory it will not move from X axis.

Answer (score 1):

So you mean every tie must not move to X axis ? If that's the case you can do it something like this :

Inside of your

```
if (result.Equals(newPreviousValue) &&  yIndex < table.GetLength(1) - 1)
{
    yIndex += 1;
    table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
}
```

You recode like this

```
if (result.Equals(newPreviousValue) &&  yIndex < table.GetLength(1) - 1)
{
     var newResult = previousValue.Contains(scoreboardWinner[2]);
     if (newResult == previousValue.Contains(scoreboardWinner[2])) 
     { 
           yIndex += 1;
           table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
     }
     else 
     {
         yIndex += 1;
         table[xIndex, yIndex] = result;
     }
}
```

Maybe that will do.

Comment: Hmm i didn't think of that . I'll try this one sir when i get home . Thank you

Comment: Please don't "sir" me . If that's what you want on your rule then I am pretty sure that is the answer